# Prevent label page scrolling to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anybody know of a way to prevent the page jumping to an input when is is changed?
Particularly if it's changed with a label button from elsewhere on the page.

This problem affects IE, Chrome Canary, FireFox, and probably some others, in-fact the only browser it doesn't seem to affect is Chrome v28.

You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/FgaWM/3/

Normally this would be a useful feature, but in my case it is quite annoying, I need a way to prevent it / override it.

I've tried forcing the scroll position with JQuery:

```
var labelPos = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scrollTop(labelPos);
```

This solution is... buggy at best, causing momentary page flicker.

Anyone have a better way?

**Edit:** I figured-out a solution :P

```
$('label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var For = $(this).attr('for');
    $('#' + For).trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Not a great solution, but... http://jsfiddle.net/MXybz/

Comment: @Dan, your "Edit" solution did the trick for me when I was using a label to hide a file input

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('label[for]').on('click', function (e) {
    var target = window[this.htmlFor];
    target.checked = !target.checked;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Use $(target).trigger('change') or you'll lose the JavaScript event.

Comment: @ErikNijland - I would rather use `$(target).trigger('click');` to make it work in more browsers.

Comment: Just a note, that manually changing `checked` *only works for checkboxes* - if you're dealing with another type of input with a label (radio buttons, or a select, for example) the manual change needs to be different.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone else... I was using the ["checkbox hack"](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) with both checkboxes *and radios* (so the accepted answer did not work for me) and my layout kept jumping around.

This is what worked for me https://codepen.io/allicarn/pen/MOgbpg

On mousedown of the label, I move the hidden (and "misplaced") input to be at the same top position as the label, so that when the browser naturally scrolls, it doesn't need to go anywhere.

Transferred here, for posterity:

```js
(function() {
  $('label[for]').filter(function() {
    var $input = $(window[this.htmlFor]);
    // Collect the labels whos inputs are offscreen and don't align to them
    return ($input.offset().left < 0) && ($input.offset().top != $(this).offset().top);
  }).on('mousedown.init', function() {
    // Move the input so that it is aligned with the label, to prevent scrolling
    $(window[this.htmlFor]).css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': $(this).offset().top
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
.container p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
  top: auto;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type="checkbox"][id],
input[type="radio"][id] {
  margin: 0;
}

label[for] {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px;
}
label[for]:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px;
}

.label-group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.label-group label[for] {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-left-width: 0;
}
.label-group label[for]:first-child {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.label-group label[for]:hover {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px;
}

.border-control:checked ~ .container {
  border-color: red;
}
.border-control:checked ~ .container .border-control__label {
  background: #ccc;
}

.font-control--red:checked ~ .container {
  color: red;
}
.font-control--red:checked ~ .container .font-control--red__label {
  background: #ccc;
}

.font-control--blue:checked ~ .container {
  color: blue;
}
.font-control--blue:checked ~ .container .font-control--blue__label {
  background: #ccc;
}

.font-control--default:checked ~ .container .font-control--default__label {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="hidden1" class="border-control" />

<input type="radio" id="hiddenrad1" name="radioDemo" class="font-control--red" />
<input type="radio" id="hiddenrad2" name="radioDemo" class="font-control--blue" />
<input type="radio" id="hiddenrad3" name="radioDemo" class="font-control--default" checked />

<div class="container">
  
  <!--  Extra stuff to make it scroll  -->
  <div>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
    <p>Consectetur consectetur deserunt est nisi irure ut cillum occaecat duis sit est sunt duis eu in in adipisicing non ullamco proident incididunt cupidatat excepteur pariatur cillum nisi excepteur mollit pariatur dolor.</p>
    <p>Cupidatat est dolore minim nulla velit anim in enim sed excepteur eiusmod ut incididunt id veniam ad tempor culpa est consequat quis voluptate duis adipisicing sed ea aliqua.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum consectetur magna culpa reprehenderit ut amet laborum esse aute esse quis sint irure cillum aliqua occaecat enim dolor nisi elit id anim velit sed consequat eu exercitation in ex pariatur velit id deserunt aute duis in pariatur mollit.</p>
  </div>
  
  <!--  These labels control inputs all the way at the top of the pen  -->
  <label for="hidden1" class="border-control__label">Change border color</label>
  
  <div class="label-group">
    <label for="hiddenrad1" class="font-control--red__label">Change font to red</label>
    <label for="hiddenrad2" class="font-control--blue__label">Change font to blue</label>
    <label for="hiddenrad3" class="font-control--default__label">Change font to default</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very clever.  I was looking for that one solution that totally fixed the inherent issue without tinkering with any of the default browser native functionality (the accepted answers does not begin to cover the breadthe of issues that come into play when you `.preventDefault()` label events).  This does the trick exactly and should be the accepted answer.  I marvel at how many times CSS has solved some core super hard DOM manipulation issues (with just a hint of JavaScript).